# Seeking improved fixed-width font rendering in Kindle for Mac reader

Tags: font, kindle

I purchased a programming book from Amazon which I'm reading on the Kindle for Mac application.  The rendering of the fixed-width font (the code examples) is just insane.  Is there a way to fix this?  Are there alternative readers that do a better job?

Comment: Kindle for Mac is still no good at this in Dec 2017. In particular for me, Kindle for Mac seems unable to render bold fixed-width fonts in a way that is visible (at least on my retina iMac). Kindle Cloud Reader (as mentioned by Eric Dorsey below) does a much better job at this on the same machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it any better if you use the Kindle Cloud Reader (read your Kindle books in a web browser)?

https://read.amazon.com/

Comment: It's entirely better, and it looks like the entire book can be downloaded in HTML for offline reading too.  Remains to be seen if that solution works on iOS devices, too...  Many thanks!